# Singularities and residues of $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{(1-e^{-z})^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We are given the meromorphic function $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{(1-e^{-z})^3}$. I know the singularities lie at $z = 2\pi \mathrm{i} k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But how do I show that the singularities are poles of order $3$ and how do I calculate the residues? I only end up with really messy calculations, so I assume there must be some sort of trick...

Comment: Are you sure the poles have order 3?  What about the zeros of $\sin z$?

Comment: I'm not sure at all

Comment: Try to calculate the $\lim_{z\to 0} z^2f(z)$.  The Residues will be $lim_{z\to 0} d/dz$ of that same expression (or similar expression at $z=2\pi i k$

Comment: Couldn't come up with any tricks for this one.  The double pole at $z=0$ has order 2, residue $3/2$.  The residues at the triple poles $z=2n\pi i$ are $3\cosh 2n\pi + i\sinh 2n\pi$  It's a messy calculation but $lim_{z\to 2n\pi i} 1/2 \cdot d^2/dz^2 (z-n\pi i)^3\sin(z)/(1-e^{-z})^3$ can be used to calculate them.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin z = \frac {1}{2i}(e^z - e^{-z})$

$\frac {\sin z}{(1-e^{-z})^3} = \frac {(e^z - e^{-z})}{2i(1-e^{-z})^3}$

multiply top and bottom by $e^{3z}$

$\frac {(e^{4z} - e^{2z})}{2i(e^z-1)^3}$
$\frac {(e^{4z} - e^{2z})}{2i(e^z-1)^3}$

$u= e^z$

$\frac {(u^4 - u^2)}{2i(u-1)^3} = \frac {u^3+u)}{2i(u-1)^2} = \frac 1{2i}( u^2 + 2u+ \frac {4}{u-1} + \frac {2}{(u-1)^2})\\
\frac 1{2i}( e^{2z} + 2e^z + \frac {4}{e^z-1} + \frac {2}{(e^z-1)^2})$

Check my work on that partial fraction decomposition.